# Connect dual displays to MacBook 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport

I have [Macbook Pro 15 Late 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp644?locale=en_US) with single Mini DisplayPort. Now I use MacBook display with external FullHD display via Mini DisplayPort->HDMI adapter. Is it possible to connect 2 external FullHD displays?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use 2 exteral monitors via 1 mini displayport > HDMI adapter. You will need a special converter. Have a look at this [youtube proof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQo8MmAUHK4). Also [Macworld](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/connect-your-mac-two-or-more-monitors-3621421/) wrote something about connecting more screens to your mac.